# Determine a maximum and minimum with one value

Tags: css, responsive-design

Is it possible to use CSS' `calc()` function together with viewport sizes to determine a maximum and minimum for a property or should I use another approach for this?

I managed to get some kind of max or min but not both for a certain value. Here is how I set a minimum value of roughly `32px` for the `font-size` property.

```
.selector {
    font-size: calc(32px + 2vw);
}
```

Unfortunately at enormous resolutions the font size would be enormous as well, what will not look as pretty as expected. Vice versa when setting a maximum size. That's why I'm looking for a solution what helps to set a both max and min value for the property.

The code above is actually pretty close to what I want but I would like to know if you guys found a better approach. The main objective is to make the "selector" to about 1/4 of the wrapper it's size at either small and big resolutions. Consider the wrapper, a parent element of the selector element what has the following properties:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 40px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the viewport with media queries, there is no automated way to set max-fontsize unfortunately.

```
.selector {
    font-size: calc(32px + 2vw);
}



@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .selector {
      font-size: 70px;
   }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .selector {
      font-size: 40px;
   }
}
```

Comment: That's such a hassle, but like you said unfortunately there is no other way of addressing this issue by only using CSS.